# Not receiving mail from php contact form

Tags: php, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Hi i have a contact form in an overlay panel, the submit action for this can be seen below. Once i submit to email.php i receive back the success from my php file but i do not receive the mail in my inbox or spam. I am using gmail to receive the mail, the php can also be seen below:

```
              items:[
                {
                    xtype:'button',
                    text: 'Submit',
                    ui: 'action-round',
                    handler: function(){
                     var contactUsComment = Ext.getCmp('contactUsForm').getValues();


                Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'email.php',
                        params : contactUsComment,
                        success: function(response){
                            var text = response.responseText;
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text); 
                        }
                       });


            <?php $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
            $recipient = "myGmailHere";
            $subject = "Contact Form";
            $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
            mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
             echo "Thank You!";
              ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your php log? Where is the script running (local server, shared hosting etc.)?

Comment: no nothing, I am just getting back the echo "Thank You!"

Comment: Is `mail` returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: I've just run this on my local box, and the mail has been received. This is probably an MTA issue.  Perhaps it is best categorized as such?

Comment: I changed where i was hosting the php file and it worked, thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is your validation?

Comment: putting validation in with sencha